# How should I go about buying 10-20 generic minifigs?

Tags: minifigures, shopping

Not a collector, just looking to fill out a few things with sort of generic minifigures. I don't care a ton about what they look like, or even if they're all unique. Just looking for a good variety of maybe 20 minifigs.

It's not obvious to me the easiest and cheapest way to do this.

Comment: BrickLink doesn't work well for "groups" of parts - for instance, you want 20 random heads, but you need to pick *one* head, and look for who has 20 of that one pattern from that mold. Let's start with this: where are you?

Comment: I looked at quite a few BrickLink stores with `figs' in the name, and high ratings, to give an example of how you could just look at any given store and choose their cheapest 20 figures - and if they're near you, and allow pickup, no shipping costs! But I didn't spot one that mentioned they allowed pickup. I know the ones near me which allow pickup, but unless you're near me, that won't necessarily help. One I use all the time has 20 figures for under $40 (Canadian) total and allows pickup, for instance.

Comment: I'm in Northern California, just north of San Jose. I'm wondering if I can just go to a Lego store nearby?

Comment: All the Lego stores I've been in in the past few years have had a build-a-minifig station of some sort. Those figures will not be the cheapest you could find, but if it's quick for you to get to Santa Clara or San Mateo, it might be your best bet. It will almost certainly be your fastest way to get figures, and almost certainly be the way to get the figures you actually want.

Comment: Don't forget that if you want 20 generic minifigs that are all different, you could choose say 5 figures with different styles of legs/arms/torso/head/hair, buy  say 4 of each type, and shuffle the parts to rebuild 20 unique figures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could suggest checking [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) stores in your area/country. It is usually cheaper to buy entire minifigure that individual parts. Unless you need specific items.

Stores have variable inventory, but you need to look for `Minifigs` section, which usually goes after `Sets`, and then `Parts` sections (again, depends on what is being sold in the store). Here you have an option to check all of them or go through individual categories. You might find minifigures you are looking for in `Town` category.

Answer (score 7):

eBay has various auctions for minifig lots; [this auction](https://www.ebay.com/itm/324261994792) has 10 for $20 (plus shipping). BrickLink might well be cheaper overall, if you can find a seller near you who will allow pickup.

I don't know the seller; I just chose the first hit for `minifig lot` that seemed to match your criteria.

Answer (score -1):

You can get 11 generic minifigs in
[one set: 40516: Everyone is Awesome](https://brickset.com/sets/40516-1)!

[image: picture of 40516 everything is awesome]

And you get lots of tiles and plates too.

Comment: Soon, sadly not quite yet

Comment: Ah, the pinnacle of woke inclusivity: reducing everyone down to a single color each! Also, BLM seem to be getting lumped in with LGBT, which I'm sure many hetero black people would find very welcoming!

Comment: @nick012000 the original choice to make [all minifigs yellow](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tags/minifigures/info) was taken back in the mid 70s and was deliberately taken to allow "children to project whatever role was required by their imagination and play", and that mostly still holds today except for licensed sets. The whole point of this set is show the inclusivity of all within the LEGO community.

Comment: @nick012000 The goal isn't to claim that race, ethnicity, sexuality, and gender identity are all the same. The message here is that people are diverse, and they should be welcomed, respected, and celebrated as they are.

Comment: @jncraton And in the process, it's saying that your one label is all that defines you - and also that if you aren't LGBT or a PoC, you're not a person.

Comment: I'm not sure these are what the question was author was looking for in regards to 'generic minifigure' they would need different heads with possibly hands to be standard figures and even the some of the hair colours aren't what you might think of as generic. Considering the price I wouldn't say these were the cheapest as well at more than $3 each if you buy as a set.

Comment: My solution is easy.  I'm sure there are cheaper ways to go, but they consume more time.  The OP asked for both.

Comment: While this might be somewhat on the OP for not clarifying their question accurately, I kind of doubt they're looking for a bunch of oddly monochrome people running through their scenery. This neat set in all honours, but it seems about the opposite to what the asker actually wants.